# Why do I need to change the Binding Source Position before I can SaveChanges

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, bindingsource

I have a small demo WinForms app. One of the Forms is my Add New Person form. I used the Details View instead of the `DataGridView` from my Data Sources. When I enter data and click the save button on the Navigator there are zero changes, However I put a `MovePrevious` and a `MoveNext` after my `AddNew` in the form `Load`, everything works as expected.

```
public partial class AddPersonForm : Form
{
    private readonly DemoContext _context;

    public AddPersonForm()
    {
        _context = new DemoContext();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        _context.People.Load();

        personBindingSource.DataSource = _context.People.Local.ToBindingList();

        personBindingSource.AddNew();
        personBindingSource.MovePrevious();
        personBindingSource.MoveNext();

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    private void personBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int changes = _context.SaveChanges();
        Debug.WriteLine("# of changes: " + changes);
    }
}
```

Why do I need to toggle the BindingSource Position before it will recognize changes and save?

Comment: You don't need to change position, in fact you need `BindingSource.EndEdit()`

Comment: I think you can just call `EndEdit()`.   doh, @RezaAghaei beat me by 5 secs ;)

Comment: EndEdit works. Thanks @RezaAghaei, to both of you really!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change the position, in fact you need to call [EndEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) of the BindingSource that applies pending changes to the underlying data source.

Changing the position causes the underlying currency manager calls `EndCurrentEdit` and this is what the `EndEdit` method of binding source does for you.

So this is what you usually want to do:

```
try
{
    this.Validate();
    bindingSource1.EndEdit();
    //Save data by dbContext.SaveChange or tableAdapter.Update
    //Set the dialog result or show a success message
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle the exception, log it and/or show a failure message
}
```