# Databinding not updating database until after move to previous or next record

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

Creating a project for school, I have a form with some user controls.

3 textboxes a checkbox and 2 buttons for navigating through the records.

When I change the text on one of the textboxes, the data will only reflect to the database when I click the "Next" or "Prev" button.

```
public partial class Navigeren : UserControl
{
    private readonly SqLiteDataAccess _sqLiteDataAccess;
    private Timer _saveTimer;
    private DataViewManager _dsView;
    public Navigeren()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _sqLiteDataAccess = new SqLiteDataAccess();
        DataBinding();
        _saveTimer = new Timer {Interval = 1000};
        _saveTimer.Tick += _saveTimer_Tick;
        _saveTimer.Start();
    }

    private void _saveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _sqLiteDataAccess.UpdatePersonen(_dsView.DataSet);
         // Tried using SqLiteDataAccess.PersonenDataSet gives me the same result.
    }

    private void DataBinding()
    {
        _dsView = SqLiteDataAccess.PersonenDataSet.DefaultViewManager;
        textId.DataBindings.Add("Text", _dsView, "Personen.id", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textNaam.DataBindings.Add("Text", _dsView, "Personen.name", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textAdres.DataBindings.Add("Text", _dsView, "Personen.adres", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        checkGehuwd.DataBindings.Add("Checked", _dsView, "Personen.gehuwd", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }

    private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[_dsView, "Personen"];
        if (cm.Position < cm.Count - 1)
        {
            cm.Position++;
        }
    }

    private void buttonPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BindingContext[_dsView, "Personen"].Position > 0)
        {
            this.BindingContext[_dsView, "Personen"].Position--;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Greetings Andy

EDIT:
SQLiteDataAccess:

```
class SqLiteDataAccess
{
    private SQLiteConnection _sqliteconnection;
    private string _database = @"Database.sqlite";

    private static DataSet _personenDataSet;
    public static DataSet PersonenDataSet
    {
        get { return _personenDataSet; }
        set { _personenDataSet = value; }
    }

    public SqLiteDataAccess()
    {
        OpenConnection();
        CreateTable();
        CreateTableGeslachten();
        CreateTableLanden();
        FillDataSet();
    }

    private void OpenConnection()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(_database))
            SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(_database);
        _sqliteconnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + _database + ";Version=3;");
        _sqliteconnection.Open();
    }

    private void CreateTable()
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE Personen (" +
                         "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                         "name VARCHAR, " +
                         "adres VARCHAR, " +
                         "gehuwd INT, " +
                         "land INT, " +
                         "geslacht INT, " +
                         "telnr VARCHAR, " +
                         "studies VARCHAR, " +
                         "geboorteDatum DATETIME, " +
                         "foto BLOB)";

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _sqliteconnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException sle)
        {

        }
    }

    private void CreateTableGeslachten()
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE Geslachten (" +
                         "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                         "geslacht TEXT," +
                         "FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Personen(geslacht));";

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _sqliteconnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertTableGeslachten();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException sle)
        {

        }
    }

    private void InsertTableGeslachten()
    {
        string sql = "INSERT INTO Geslachten(geslacht) VALUES('Man'), ('Vrouw');";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _sqliteconnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    private void CreateTableLanden()
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "CREATE TABLE Landen (" +
                         "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                         "land TEXT," +
                         "FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES Personen(land));";

            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, _sqliteconnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertTableLanden();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException sle)
        {
        }
    }  

    public void Insert(string name, string adres, bool gehuwd, int land, int geslacht, string telnr, string studies,
        string geboorteDatum, byte[] foto)
    {
        var sql =
            new StringBuilder(
                "insert into Personen (name, adres, gehuwd, land, geslacht, telnr, studies,  geboorteDatum) values ('");
        sql.Append(name).Append("','")
            .Append(adres).Append("','")
            .Append(Convert.ToInt32(gehuwd)).Append("','")
            .Append(land).Append("','")
            .Append(geslacht).Append("','")
            .Append(telnr).Append("','")
            .Append(studies).Append("','")
            .Append(geboorteDatum).Append("');");
        //  .Append(foto).Append(");");            
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql.ToString(), _sqliteconnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public void FillDataSet()
    {
        SqLiteDataAccess.PersonenDataSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            string query = "select * from Personen";
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, _sqliteconnection);
            da.Fill(PersonenDataSet, "Personen");
            string query2 = "select id, geslacht from geslachten";
            SQLiteDataAdapter da2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query2, _sqliteconnection);
            da2.Fill(PersonenDataSet, "Geslachten");
            string query3 = "select id, land from Landen";
            SQLiteDataAdapter da3 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query3, _sqliteconnection);
            da3.Fill(PersonenDataSet, "Landen");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public void UpdatePersonen(DataSet ds)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "select * from Personen";
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, _sqliteconnection);
            SQLiteCommandBuilder sqLiteCommandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Update(ds, "Personen");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome! The text box will file an OnChange event when you change the text. Do you have any code that catches that event?

Comment: Thanks! No i do not have any event for the OnChange event, u think i need to fire a event there?

Comment: Please can you explain what is SqLiteDataAccess. Is it an Entity Framework DbContext derived class ? If it is, you probably have to call _sqLiteDataAccess.SaveChanges(). Else can you provide us the implementation of the UpdatePersonen() method ?

Comment: I have added the SQLiteDataAccess class file.

Comment: @AndyGybels Yes. When you do something on the user interface, there needs to be a way in the code behind to make something happen. That's called an OnChange. Read up on OnChange events and when you have an answer, post it back here.

Comment: @RobLang, i thought databinding eliminated the need for manualy firing events? And why will it work when i click the "Next" or "Prev" button.

Comment: @AndyGybels yes, but this would be the next place to check as the bindings don't seem to resolve.

Comment: @RobLang is there a way to force the binding to resolve on the OnChange event?

Comment: Only by accessing the context directly. I'm afraid that I've just reached the limit of my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the position, you just need to call [`EndCurrentEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerbase.endcurrentedit(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `BindingManagerBase` before save:

```
this.BindingContext[datasource, "datamember"].EndCurrentEdit();
```

---

**Some Notes**

*Use BindingSource.*

I recommend using a [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxxf124e(v=vs.110).aspx) component as data source which you want to use for data-binding. Then set the `DataSource` and `DataMember` of the `BindingSource` to the values which you want:

- It enables you to perform data-binding at design time.
- It enables you to use its methods and properties to navigation, add, remove and so on.
- You can use it's sorting and filtering properties.

*Use BindingNavigator.*

Also use [`BindingNavigator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zhc8d2f(v=vs.110).aspx) control as a navigation toolbar. It's enough to set its `BindingSource` property to the `BindingSource` component which you used for data-binding, then its navigation button will do the job of navigation for you.

*Also take a look at:*

- [Why do I need to change the Binding Source Position before I can SaveChanges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270664/why-do-i-need-to-change-the-binding-source-position-before-i-can-savechanges)
  Describes why changing position also does the trick.
- [Equivalent of MoveNext in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805229/equivalent-of-movenext-in-vb-net)
  Shows you how to create a rapid data application using designer features, data-binding, `BindingSource` and `BindingNavigator` using drag and drop. Also it share some useful links about these features.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805229/equivalent-of-movenext-in-vb-net)?